# Shortcut to view the assembly output of a python script's process

Tags: python, assembly, assemblies, crystal-lang

I learned from [this post](http://patshaughnessy.net/2016/11/26/learning-to-read-x86-assembly-language) that you can use Crystal to compile Ruby into native machine code and generates its asm version.

So I'm wondering if there is a similar tool for python.

I know that dis can disassemble byte code, but the output is not the native processor's assembly code as the Ruby one provides.

The easiest way I can think of is to use a freezer like py2exe to compile the script into executable and then use a debugger to step in, but that's quite low-tech compared to Crystal...

Comment: CPython is a pure interpreter; it doesn't ever JIT compile to native machine code.  You could of course single-step the code of the interpreter...  There are other python implementations that *do* JIT or ahead-of-time compile, though.

Comment: py2exe doesn't compile Python code into native machine code, it just compiles Python code into bytecode and bundles the bytecode files into a zip file.

Comment: PyInstaller works the same way, it just bundles everything into a single executable and extracts everything into a temporary directory when you run it. Because of the highly dynamic nature of the Python language you can't really meaningfully compile it into native machine code.

Comment: Also, Crystal does not compile Ruby. Crystal compiles Crystal (which just happens to have a lot in common with Ruby). For example, the program `foo = []` is valid Ruby but not valid Crystal.